# probabilities in games of chances

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to create a blackjack game.

I have some simple questions which however I need to be verified.

From the maths and programming point of view, a blackjack 1 deck game contains 52 cards which can be shuffled allowing us to obtain 52! sets of cards arrangements.

My question is if the rules of this game were created in such way so that if you would play this game for very many times, let's say X times, finally you would end losing a small portion of your total bet, due to the fact that the rules of this game were built this way. So basically due to the arrangements of the cards and probabilities and due to the rules of the game, this game ensures a house edge.

It is not the maths of this game that ensure its house edge of around 0.8% .

So my question is if I want to develop a blackjack game, or a roulette game, I would just need a RNG and a shuffling algorithm like fisher-yatte to shuffle the cards/numbers and then simply apply the game rules to my game?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to develop the blackjack game, the only thing you need is to develop the game. Why is the shuffling an issue?

Comment: I was just curious if I need to do anything else than follow the strict rules of the game. Meaning if there needs something to be done except shuffling the cards, giving them to the player+dealer, and continue to follow the game rules. Something such as having to adjust the maths of the game in order to keep that payout on the long term or something else. Because I am not sure if I just follow the rules correctly, then the game will ensure a house edge of under 1% and a payout of 99% to the players, on the long term. I know what a payout is.

Comment: No, you definitely do not need to rig the math in order to make the house win. A 0.8% edge is actually pretty high, most casino games will go with a 0.4-0.6% edge. Having any edge at all means that if the player keeps playing long enough, the house will eventually get all of the players money. If the house takes too much of the players money too fast, then it won't be fun, and the player will leave before losing everything.

Comment: @milestyle thanks for the reply. This is what I was looking for. However my question is ... is this 0.5% edge ensured by the RNG or how do I manage to get a 0.4% edge instead of a 0.6% edge? Or is it from the number of decks used in the game?

Comment: @nevergone Rigging the RNG is cheating, even if you do it in the players favor. Adding another deck will discourage card counting, but not do much else. The best way to manage the edge is by the variation of the rules that you implement. For example in one variation the dealer must hit on 17; it's called H17. If the dealer stands on 17, it's called S17. S17 is about 0.2% better for the player than H17.  Lots of places in vegas will have it written on the tables which version it is.

Comment: @milestyle I was hoping that the RNG should not be altered. Thank you very much for the explanations. I finally understand.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you want to implement, if you need some flashy look or multiplayer, you may need some GUI or game frameworks. But to code just a plain blackjack game, you don't need anything than plain rules.

Shuffle shouldn't be an issue: lots of languages have built-in shuffle algorithms in functions like `shuffle()` that works well. You could just traverse the array

```
for(int i=0; i<cards.length; ++i) {
  int rnd = random(0,cards.length);
  card tmp = cards[rnd];
  cards[rnd] = cards[i];
  cards[i] = tmp;
}
```